# Loop through column matching data in workbook and return a value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have been trying to adapt the following code to
Loop through column A of Sheet 1 and for each value in column A search the whole workbook for it's matching value (which will be found in another sheet also in column A). When a match is found, return the value found in the same row but from column F.

```
Sub Return_Results_Entire_Workbook()
    searchValueSheet = "Sheet2"
    searchValue = Sheets(searchValueSheet).Range("A1").Value
    returnValueOffset = 5
    outputValueSheet = "Sheet2"
    outputValueCol = 2
    outputValueRow = 1

    Sheets(outputValueSheet).Range(Cells(outputValueRow, outputValueCol), Cells(Rows.Count, outputValueCol)).Clear
    wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For I = 1 To wsCount
        If I <> Sheets(searchValueSheet).Index And I <> Sheets(outputValueSheet).Index Then
            'Perform the search, which is a two-step process below
            Set Rng = Worksheets(I).Cells.Find(What:=searchValue, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
                
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                rangeLoopAddress = Rng.Address
            
                Do
                    Set Rng = Sheets(I).Cells.FindNext(Rng)
                    Sheets(outputValueSheet).Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, outputValueCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1, outputValueCol).Value = Sheets(I).Range(Rng.Address).Offset(0, returnValueOffset).Value
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> rangeLoopAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

The code above works but only for the first row of data on Sheet1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of arrays where each index of main array would be the dataset A:F from each worksheet:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim WK As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim MasterArray() As Variant
Dim WkArray As Variant

'create master aray
ReDim MasterArray(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1) 'As many indexes as worksheets -1 (because master sheet does not count)
i = 1

For Each WK In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WK.Name <> "Hoja1" Then 'exclude master sheet witch search values
        LR = WK.Range("A" & WK.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non-blank row
        WkArray = WK.Range("A1:F" & LR).Value 'take all values in A:F to singlearray
        MasterArray(i) = WkArray
        Erase WkArray
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next WK

'now in Master array you have in each index all the values
' as example, if you call MasterArray(1)(1, 1) it will return cell value A1 from first worksheet

Set WK = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1") 'master sheet witch search values

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    LR = WK.Range("A" & WK.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last non-blank row
    For i = 1 To LR Step 1 'for each row in master sheet until last non blank
        For j = 1 To UBound(MasterArray) Step 1 'for each dataset in masterarray
            WkArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(MasterArray(j), , 1)) 'first column of dataset (A column)
            
            If IsError(Application.Match(WK.Range("A" & i).Value, WkArray, 0)) = False Then 'if value exists get F
                WK.Range("B" & i).Value = .VLookup(WK.Range("A" & i).Value, MasterArray(j), 6, 0)
                Erase WkArray
                Exit For
            End If
            
            Erase WkArray
        Next j
    Next i
End With

Erase MasterArray
Set WK = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code first creates the main array named `MasterArray`. Then it loops trough each value on column A from Master Sheet (named `Hoja1` in my example) and checks if the value exists in each subarray. If it does then returns columns F from dataset and keep looping.

After executing code I get this output:

[image]

Notice value `2` returns nothing because it does not exist in any of the other sheets.

Comment: Hi There, thank you so much for your response and code. I have run the macro and it only returns values for about 1/4 of the rows. I have checked several of the blank rows and there are matches in the workbook. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: @Bee Edit your original question, add your input and expected output and some examples where it's failing. Without looking at your data I can't know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the solution works beautifully. The issue I was having was some of the data being stored as text rather than numbers and vice-versa. Once fixed, the macro is working perfectly. Thank you again for your assistance!